# how 1 App showing multiple app-ads.txt on 2 admob account?

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-console, app-ads.txt

We are living with my friend in same house, i have my own website+admob+play console and he has another website+admob+play console.  When i sharing an app on my play console. app-ads.txt is showing both admob.  His admob app-ads.txt is giving danger with red sign. mine admob app-ads.txt is been green. Becouse in my play console i am writing my own website. How can his admob app-ads.txt finding my game? We can sharing games help please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of the apps (lets call it **App X**) which have ads from **AdMob A** account, this app (**App X**) have a website listed in google play that have app-ads.txt pointing to **AdMob B** account by mistake.

Just go to this app store listing in Google Play console and change the website.

Comment: already the websites are different. Thats why i am shocked and need help... :(